# Recebo NULL do STRTOK?

Tags: c, null

Olá,
estou a usar strtok para fazer a divisão de uma string em palavras. A minha ideia era a seguir à palavra `REMOVE` eliminava a próxima palavra do texto.

```
void algorithm(node **root, char *line){
    char *pch = strtok(line, " ");
    while(pch != NULL){
        if(strcmp(pch, "REMOVE")==0){
            pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
            if(pch == NULL){
                printf("error?");
            }
            removeNode(&(*root),pch);
        }else{
            insert(&(*root), pch);
        }
        pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
}
```

Porque é que a seguir ao `pch = strtok(NULL, " ");` tenho sempre `pch = NULL` ?

Nota: já testei com ficheiros grandes e um REMOVE lá no meio e o `pch` depois dessa operação dá sempre `NULL`, se a operação for no fim do ciclo a variavel `pch` já não fica `NULL`.

Comment: Neste caso você não deveria utilizar strncmp(pch, "REMOVE", 6) e não um simples strcmp?

Comment: O problema não está na comparação, está é na chamada do pch = strtok(NULL, " "). Vou explicar quando eu leio um "REMOVE", vou à seguinte palavra com o comando pch = strtok(NULL, " ") e mando remover ela. O problema esta aqui quando eu tento aceder à próxima palavra o valor retornado para pch é NULL.

Comment: Mas você não está só comparando os 6 caracteres da string apontada por pch com "REMOVE", está comparando toda a string que se inicia em pch com "REMOVE". Só será igual se "REMOVE" for o final da string.

Comment: Fiz o teste com strncmp(pch, "REMOVE", 6) e o erro continua o mesmo, porque o problema não esta na comparação está sim na atribuição de pch que dá sempre null.

Comment: Desculpe, me confundi com os comandos. Você está certo em utilizar strcmp.

Comment: Verifica se a funcao `removeNode()` altera o `pch`?

Comment: `&(*apontador)` é o mesmo que `apontador` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desisti do `strtok()` e estou a fazer a leitura das palavras uma à uma é muito mais eficiente e não gasto tanto espaço em memória.

```
while(scanf("%s ", word) > 0){
            if(removeNext){
                removeNode(&root, word);    
                removeNext = 0;
            }
            else if(strcmp(word, "REMOVE") != 0){
                i = 0;
                while(i < sizeof(word)){
                    word[i] = tolower(word[i]);
                    i++;
                }
                insert(&root, word);    
            }
            else if(strcmp(word, "REMOVE")==0){
                removeNext = 1;
            }
        }
```